# Перенос нужных значений из одного JSON в другой

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Подскажите, как из одного файла JSON перенести определенные значения (ключ:значение) в другой файл JSON.
Вот пример кода:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "time": 0,
        "name": "Арсений",
        "surname": "Савинков",
        "balance": 0,
        "online": false,
        "admin": true,
        "info": "Администратор"
}
```

(Нужно это сделать с помощью JavaScript)

Comment: наверно js  не умеет записывать в файл, нужен ЯП который имеет такую возможность ...к примеру node.js или php  или другой

Comment: @MaximLensky Все отлично записывается в файл мне из одного файла json нужно перенести некоторые значения в другой в этом и заключается проблема.

Comment: можно только в переменную записать, или в localStorage, sessionStorage засунуть

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Мне именно перенести нужно из одного файла в другой допустим переменную info перенести в файл info.json но чтобы при переносе значения которые установлены не изменились. :)

Comment: уточни пожалуйста у тебя бразуерный JS или серверный?

Comment: @singlesly Node.js

Answer (score 2):

```js
(() => {

    const fs = require("fs");

    // читаешь содержимое из файла
    const content = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/source.json", {
        encoding: "utf8"
    });

    // преобразовываешь в объект
    const json = JSON.parse(String(content));

    // производишь манипуляции
    const dist = {
        id: json.id,
        name: json.name,
        admin: json.admin
    };

    // преобразоываешь в строку
    const string =  JSON.stringify(dist)

    // записываешь в результирующий файл
    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/dist.json", string);

})();
```

Comment: ничего не добавляется к сожалению в другой файл.

Comment: опиши проблему, у меня все работает.

Comment: При выполнении кода не добавляет в файл (как вы его назвали /dist.json) значения а просто создает его и пишет в нем {}

Comment: значит объект dist у тебя пустой. Разбирай внимательней в своей ситуаций. Это не магия.